# Hibernate trying to update view

Tags: java, hibernate

For complicated reasons, I have a view defined in my database and I want hibernate to be able to read this view, so I mapped it just like it was a regular table. This all seems to be working fine in production.

Now I'm running a test and it's blowing up. I turned the hibernate show sql and sql comments on and here's what I found:

```
Hibernate: /* FROM PostponeDateLimit WHERE postponeDate>=? AND postponeDate <=? AND controlCode = ? ORDER BY postponeDate ASC */ select postponeda0_.REQUEST_DATE as REQUEST1_5_, postponeda0_.COURTLOCATION as COURTLOC2_5_, postponeda0_.ALLOWED as ALLOWED5_, postponeda0_.POSTPONED as POSTPONED5_, postponeda0_.DATECAP as DATECAP5_ from POSTPONE_DATE_VIEW postponeda0_ where postponeda0_.REQUEST_DATE>=? and postponeda0_.REQUEST_DATE<=? and postponeda0_.COURTLOCATION=? order by postponeda0_.REQUEST_DATE ASC    
Hibernate: /* update com.acs.gs.juror.pojo.PostponeDateLimit */ update POSTPONE_DATE_VIEW set ALLOWED=?, POSTPONED=?, DATECAP=? where REQUEST_DATE=? and COURTLOCATION=?    
Hibernate: /* update com.acs.gs.juror.pojo.PostponeDateLimit */ update POSTPONE_DATE_VIEW set ALLOWED=?, POSTPONED=?, DATECAP=? where REQUEST_DATE=? and COURTLOCATION=?    
Hibernate: /* update com.acs.gs.juror.pojo.PostponeDateLimit */ update POSTPONE_DATE_VIEW set ALLOWED=?, POSTPONED=?, DATECAP=? where REQUEST_DATE=? and COURTLOCATION=?    
Hibernate: /* update com.acs.gs.juror.pojo.PostponeDateLimit */ update POSTPONE_DATE_VIEW set ALLOWED=?, POSTPONED=?, DATECAP=? where REQUEST_DATE=? and COURTLOCATION=?    
Hibernate: /* update com.acs.gs.juror.pojo.PostponeDateLimit */ update POSTPONE_DATE_VIEW set ALLOWED=?, POSTPONED=?, DATECAP=? where REQUEST_DATE=? and COURTLOCATION=?    
Hibernate: /* update com.acs.gs.juror.pojo.PostponeDateLimit */ update POSTPONE_DATE_VIEW set ALLOWED=?, POSTPONED=?, DATECAP=? where REQUEST_DATE=? and COURTLOCATION=?    
Hibernate: /* update com.acs.gs.juror.pojo.PostponeDateLimit */ update POSTPONE_DATE_VIEW set ALLOWED=?, POSTPONED=?, DATECAP=? where REQUEST_DATE=? and COURTLOCATION=?    
Hibernate: /* update com.acs.gs.juror.pojo.PostponeDateLimit */ update POSTPONE_DATE_VIEW set ALLOWED=?, POSTPONED=?, DATECAP=? where REQUEST_DATE=? and COURTLOCATION=?    
Hibernate: /* update com.acs.gs.juror.pojo.PostponeDateLimit */ update POSTPONE_DATE_VIEW set ALLOWED=?, POSTPONED=?, DATECAP=? where REQUEST_DATE=? and COURTLOCATION=?
Hibernate: /* update com.acs.gs.juror.pojo.PostponeDateLimit */ update POSTPONE_DATE_VIEW set ALLOWED=?, POSTPONED=?, DATECAP=? where REQUEST_DATE=? and COURTLOCATION=?
2012-07-18 16:07:44,503 35529 WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter | SQL Error: 4406, SQLState: S1000
2012-07-18 16:07:44,503 35529 ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter | Update or insert of view or function 'EJUROR_POSTPONE_DATE_VIEW' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.
```

So updating the view is causing the exception.

Only the first query is being initiated by me. The updates appear to be created by hibernate for some strange reason. I can't for the life of me figure out why and why it's doing it on my local test box and not on our live box.

Here's my hibernate mapping:

```
<class name="com.pojo.PostponeDateLimit" table="POSTPONE_DATE_VIEW">
    <composite-id class="com.acs.gs.juror.pojo.PostponeDateLimitKey" mapped="true">
        <key-property name="postponeDate" type="calendar" column="REQUEST_DATE"/>
        <key-property name="controlCode" column="COURTLOCATION"/>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="maxCount" column="ALLOWED"/>
    <property name="postponedCount" column="POSTPONED"/>
    <property name="dateCap" column="DATECAP"/>
</class>
```

Does anyone have an insight at all?

Comment: Can you run your test on debug? If so, set a breakpoint exception on SQLException, and there you will be able to see what's going on and why it is issuing those updates.

Comment: @Luciano I'm currently looking for the hibernate source code for my version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the Entity read-only as per [Hibernate documents](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch12.html#readonly-api)

In this case probably best to make the com.pojo.PostponeDateLimit class immutable. This will also catch any code that tries to change the data - which I suspect is what is happening not Hibernate doing something

Comment: It appears that you have to set something in the session in order to do this? If so, how do i do this with Spring?

Comment: ended up putting mutable="false" on the class definition in the mapping file. That seems to have fixed it. Didn't find that in the hibernate docs by the way. :(

Comment: Now, does anyone know why hibernate feels the need to update these rows in the database?

Comment: See what happens when immutable - the code that tries to change should throw an exception

Comment: My code was never changing this, otherwise it would be flowing up in production. The line it blows up on when the update is run is the select query shown above. Hibernate is initiating the update on its own volition.